# Position of な in this sentence

Tags: adjectives, nouns, particle-な

静か**な**人

人**な**静か

Which comes first the subject and then the adjective, or the adjective then the subject?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar#Word_order:_head_final_and_left_branching

Answer (score 2):

**静か**is a **な** adjective, where as **人** is the noun. When you use **な** adjective before a noun, the **な** will be attached with the adjective, not with the noun.

So, **静かな人** is correct, **人な静か** wrong.

Let's take another example, **[好き]{すき}→Like**

Ex:1

> [私]{わたし}の[好き]{すき}な[花]{はな}はばらです。 
>   →My favorite flower is rose.

Ex:2

> [私]{わたし}はばらが[好き]{すき}です。 
>   →I like rose.

Though you are expressing the same feeling with the above two example, but the use of **な** adjective is different. When **な** adjective is used in the end of a sentence, **な** is simply omitted.